# Sending only updated rows to a client

Tags: postgresql, time, transactions

I'd like to create a web service that allows a client to fetch all rows in a table, and then later allows the client to only fetch new or updated rows.

The simplest implementation seems to be to send the current timestamp to the client, and then have the client ask for rows that are newer than the timestamp in the following request.

It seems that this is doable by keeping an "updated_at" column with a timestamp set to NOW() in update and insert triggers, and then querying newer rows, and also passing down the value of NOW().

The problem is that if there are uncommitted transactions, these transactions will set updated_at to the **start time** of the transaction, not the **commit time**.

As a result, this simple implementation doesn't work, because rows can be lost since they can appear with a timestamp in the past.

I have been unable to find any simple solution to this problem, despite the fact that it seems to be a very common need: any ideas?

Possible solutions:

1. Keep a monotonic timestamp in a table, update it at the start of every transaction to MAX(NOW(), last_timestamp + 1) and use it as a row timestamp. Problem: this effectively means that all write transactions are fully serialized and lock the whole database since they conflict on the update time table.
2. At the end of the transaction, add a mapping from NOW() to the time in an update table like the above solution. This seems to require to take an explicit lock and use a sequence to generate non-temporal "timestamps" because just using an UPDATE on a single row would cause rollbacks in SERIALIZABLE mode.
3. Somehow have PostgreSQL, at commit time, iterate over all updated rows and set updated_at to a monotonic timestamp
4. Somehow have PostgreSQL itself maintain a table of transaction commit times, which it doesn't seem to do at the moment

Using the built-in xmin column also seems impossible, because VACUUM can trash it.

It would be nice to be able to do this in the database without modifications to all updates in the application.

What is the usual way this is done?

**The problem with the naive solution**

In case it's not obvious, this is the problem with using NOW() or CLOCK_TIMESTAMP():

1. At time 1, we run NOW() or CLOCK_TIMESTAMP() in a transaction, which gives 1 and we update a row setting time 1 as the update time
2. At time 2, a client fetches all rows, and we tell him that we gave it all rows until time 2
3. At time 3, the transaction commits with "time 1" in the updated_at field
4. The client asks for updated rows since time 2 (the time he got from the previous full fetch request), we query for updated_at >= 2 and we return nothing, instead of returning the row that is just added
5. That row is lost and will never seen by the client

Comment: That still is not the commit time, so it will not work. I.e. the transaction might commit a second after clock_timestamp() is called, and the update is lost if a client updated in the meantime.

Comment: That doesn't work either for the same reason (unless you do it under a lock).

Comment: Running into this exact problem as well, looking for answers.

Comment: My best idea is to have updates to a table also do inserts into a queue table. Jobs in the queue table get popped off and later update the 'updated_at' field.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole proposition goes against some of the underlying fundamentals of an ACID-compliant RDBMS like PostgreSQL. Time of transaction start (e.g. `current_timestamp()`) and other time-based metrics are meaningless as a measure of what a particular client has received or not. Abandon the whole idea.

Assuming that your clients connect through a persistent session to the database you can follow this procedure:

- When the session starts, `CREATE TEMP UNLOGGED TABLE` for the session user. This table contains nothing but the PK and the last update time of the table you want to fetch the data from.
- The client polls for new data and receives only those records that have a PK not yet in the temp table or an existing PK but a newer last update time. Currently uncommitted transactions are invisible but will be retrieved at the next poll for new or updated records. The update time is required because there is no way to delete records from the temp tables of all concurrent clients.
- The PK and last update time of retrieved record are stored in the temp table.
- When the user closes the session, the temp table is deleted.

If you want to persist the retrieved records over multiple sessions for each client or the client disconnects after every query, then you need a regular table but then I would suggest to also add the oid of the user such that all users can use a single table for keeping track of the retrieved records. In that latter case you can create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on the table with your data which deletes the PK from the table with fetched records, for all users in one sweep. On their next poll the clients will then get the updated record.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column, which will be used to track what record has been sent to a client:

```
alter table table_under_view
  add column access_order int null;

create sequence table_under_view_access_order_seq
  owned by table_under_view.access_order;

create function table_under_view_reset_access_order()
  returns trigger
  language plpgsql
as $func$
  new.access_order := null;
$func$;

create trigger table_under_view_reset_access_order_before_update
  before update on table_under_view
  for each row execute procedure table_under_view_reset_access_order();

create index table_under_view_access_order_idx
  on table_under_view (access_order);

create index table_under_view_access_order_where_null_idx
  on table_under_view (access_order)
  where (access_order is null);
```

(You could use a `before insert on table_under_view` trigger too, to ensure only `NULL` values are inserted into `access_order`).

You need to update this column after transactions with `INSERT`s & `UPDATE`s on this table is finished, but before any client query your data. You cannot do anything just *after* a transaction finished, so let's do it before a query happens. You can do this with a function, f.ex:

```
create function table_under_access(from_access int)
  returns setof table_under_view
  language sql
as $func$
  update table_under_view
  set    access_order = nextval('table_under_view_access_order_seq'::regclass)
  where  access_order is null;

  select *
  from   table_under_view
  where  access_order > from_access;
$func$;
```

Now, your first "chunk" of data (which will fetch all rows in a table), looks like:

```
select *
from   table_under_access(0);
```

The key element after this is that your client needs to process every "chunk" of data to determine which is the greatest `access_order` it last got (unless you include it in your result with f.ex. window functions, but if you're going to process the results - which seems highly likely - you don't need that). Always use that for the subsequent calls.

You can add an `updated_at` column too for ordering your results, if you want to.

You can also use a view + [rule](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-views.html#RULES-SELECT)(s) for the last part (instead of the function), to make it more transparent.